# Como manipular o MongoDB fora do arquivo de configuração?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

estou estudando NodeJS e MongoDB, até consigo fazer a conexão e alguns testes no banco, mas gostaria de poder exportar a conexão com o banco pra poder fazer insert/find/remove/etc de qualquer lugar da minha aplicação, tipo um module.exports da variável, pensei mais ou menos assim:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'myproject';

// Create a new MongoClient
const client = new MongoClient(url);

var banco;
// Use connect method to connect to the Server
client.connect(function(err) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log("Connected successfully to server");

    banco = client.db(dbName);
});

module.exports = banco;
```

mas obviamente... isso não funciona!

Comment: É só exportar o `client` e importar aonde quiser usar.

Comment: Mas aí eu vou ter que ficar escreverndo client.connect toda hora, e se um dia eu quiser atualizar o banco para um driver mais recente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei optando pelo pacote [express-mongo-db](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mongo-db), não era bem o que queria, mas com umas 3 linhas de código foi possivel chamar o banco a cada requisição:

```
var app = require('express')();

var expressMongoDb = require('express-mongo-db');
app.use(expressMongoDb('mongodb://localhost/test'));

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    req.db // => Db object
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde eu acabei fazendo um comentário atravessado acredito que porque faz muito tempo que não utilizo o driver nativo, bom vamos la uma das formas de se carregar o driver com a conexão é utilizando [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) para retorno da conexão no callback:

> mongo.js

Aqui no nosso arquivo `mongo.js` aonde realizamos a conexão à instancia do mongodb, mas ainda não nos conectamos ao nosso banco de collections:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'

module.exports.connectMongodb = async() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        MongoClient.connect(url,{ useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, db) => {
            if(err)  return reject('Não foi possivel se conectar a instância!!')
            console.log('instance connected')
            resolve(db)          
        })
    })
}
```

> index.js

Agora em nosso index vamos chamar nossa promise:

```
const {connectMongodb} = require('./mongo')

const start = async() => {
    try {
        const db = await connectMongodb()
        const dbo = db.db('mydboMongo')
        dbo.createCollection('user', (err, dbs) => {
            if(err){
                return console.log(err)
            }
            console.log('collection created')
            db.close()
        })
        dbo.collection('user').insertOne({
            username: 'carlos',
            disabled: '2'
        }, (err, res) => {
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            }
            console.log('document inserted')
            db.close()
        })            
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
}
start()
```

Aqui ocorre o seguinte eu invoco nossa promise e adiciono `await` para que espere nossa promise ser resolvida ou rejeitada, lembrando que await só tera uso em function definidas como `async` e o nosso metodo for uma promise outro detalhe sem o trycatch não há como capturar e tratar o erro da nossa promise e sua aplicação iria crashar.

Após o resolve da nossa conexão eu tenho o db que é onde esta nossa conexão na instancia então realizamos a conexão ao nosso banco de collections `db.db('mydboMongo')` lembrando que aqui ele se conecta ou cria nosso banco se ja existir ele apenas conecta.
Após ser conectado realizamos duas ações, uma de criar uma coleção e outra de inserir um item na coleção criada, eu estou um pouco enferrujado com o driver nativo, fiquei muito dependente do mongoose, mas fica ai uma dica de como carregar a conexão para seus arquivos.

Para seu exemplo ficaria assim a conexão:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
// Database Name
const dbName = 'myproject';
// Create a new MongoClient
const client = new MongoClient(url);

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
module.exports.connectMongo = async() => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        client.connect(function(err, db) {
            //assert.equal(null, err);
            if(err) return reject('Could not connect.')                
            console.log("Connected successfully to server");
            resolve(db)

        });
    })
}
```

No exemplo que eu defini a cima não realizei a conexão previa ao banco de collections para poder exportar db que possui o método `db.close()`.